# How to add URL to list using JavaScript

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest

I have a list with a title and a url. I'm trying to add a new url using [this function](http://www.plusconsulting.com/blog/2013/05/crud-on-list-items-using-rest-services-jquery/)

```
function addListItem(url, listname, metadata, success, failure) {

    // Prepping our update
    var item = $.extend({
        "__metadata": { "type": getListItemType(listname)}
    }, metadata);

    // Executing our add
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data); // Returns the newly created list item information
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });

}
```

I can set the title using this metadata item:

```
metadata = { Title: 'myTitle' }
```

But how can I set the url in this context? This doesn't work:

```
metadata = { Title: 'myTitle', Url: 'http://myspurl' }
```

Comment: as per your program you can only pass one parameter in metadata?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to set Url Field value in SharePoint REST specify the following JSON object:

```
URL: {Url: 'http://www.microsoft.com',Description: 'MSFT'}
```

where `URL` is the name of a field.

Example

```
var metadata = { Title: 'myTitle', URL: {Url: 'http://www.microsoft.com',Description: 'MSFT'}};
```

Comment: Or simply `URL: "http://www.google.com, Google"`